# Add nonce to style inline

Tags: css, content-security-policy

```
<div .... style="background-color: #fff" ..... </div>
```

How to add nonce (CSP) to this style? It is not between style tags as you see.

Comment: Why do you need CSP for inline styles? If your code is allowed to be executed on another app, you shouldn't need to do anything extra.

Comment: Nonces are unsupported for this kind ib inline style. You can use `'hash-source'` + ['unsafe-hashes'](https://csplite.com/csp149/), but Safari does not support these.

Answer (score 7):

Only style and script are nonceable elements in CSP level 2, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#script-src-the-nonce-attribute. You might be able to do this in CSP level 3, but unless you can target only specific browsers that support it, you should move your style to a style tag with nonce or a css file.

Edit 2024-02-01: In CSP level 3, which has good browser support now, you can use 'unsafe-hashes' in addition to the hash of the attribute code to allow attribute styles/scripts. Unless you only have a few attributes with static content that need hashes you should still try to move it.

Answer (score 0):

There are the most efficient and recomended ways to add CSP to an Html web project or for a ReactJS-based project.

Add CSP resource to Meta tag of the Head tags of the Main Html file.

Example
Main HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="directives">
    <!-- Other meta tags, title, etc. -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your HTML content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Modifyed version of Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://cdn.example.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; img-src 'self' https://www.example.com">
```

Use style-src to specify the following URLs for the Styles only.

Also, unsafe-hashes supports to apply CSP resources.